# swap each element with its neighbour element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I need to write a program. This method will take integer array as input and return array where each value is swapped with its neighbour element. In case the array has odd count, then last element is not swapped.

```
int[] array ={111,77,88,44,32,11,13,25,44}
```

Result:

```
    finalarray= 77,111,44,88,11,32,25,13,44
```

I tried using nested for loops but didnt get it

```
public static int[] swap(int array[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= i; j++) {
                int temp = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(array[k] + " ");
        }

        //Desired output 17,111,44,88,11,32,25,13,44
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] number = { 111, 17, 88, 44, 32, 11, 13, 25, 44 };
        number = swap(number);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the code you tried so far ?!

Anyway

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        if(i+1 >= array.length) {
            break;
        }
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[] array ={111,77,88,44,32,11,13,25,44};
    int[] output = new int[array.length];

    for(int x = 0; x < array.length - 1; x += 2) {
        output[x] = array[x + 1];
        output[x+1] = array[x];
    }
    if(array.length % 2 != 0) {
        output[output.length-1] = array[array.length-1];
    }
```

You just have to loop through the array, and populate the new array with the swapped values.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
public static final <T> void swap (T[] a, int i, int j) {
T t = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = t;
}

public static final <T> void swap (List<T> l, int i, int j) {
Collections.<T>swap(l, i, j);
}

private void test() {
String [] a = {"Hello", "Goodbye"};
swap(a, 0, 1);
System.out.println("a:"+Arrays.toString(a));
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
swap(l, 0, 1);
System.out.println("l:"+l);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all you have a function to swap the two elements like this:

```
public void swap(int [] array , int firstIndex , int secondIndex){
    int temp = array[firstIndex];
    array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
    array[secondIndex] = temp;
 }
//Now it's time to navigate over the array like this:

for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length -1;i+=2){
        swap(array,i,i+1);
     }
```

Comment: You are incrementing 1 element at a time so you will swap 1 and 2 then 2 and 3 instead of then swapping 3 and 4. the loop increment should be 2

Comment: Yeah I forgot it,Sorry :(